# Limit selected results by unique selected IDs when using left joins

Tags: mysql, left-join, mariadb, limit

I have a table users and some other tables like images and products

Table users:

```
 user_id   user_name
1   andrew
2   lutz
3   sophie
4   michael
5   peter
6   oscor
7   anton
8   billy
9   henry
10  jon
```

Tables images:

```
user_id   img_type  img_url
  1 0 url1
  1 1 url4
  2 0 url5
  7 0 url7
  8 0 url8
  9 1 url9
```

Table Products

```
user_id   prod_id
  1   5
  1   55
  2   555
  8   5555
  9   5
  9   55
```

I use this kind of SELECT:

```
SELECT * FROM 
(SELECT user.user_id,user.user_name, img.img_type, prod.prod_id FROM
    users 
    LEFT JOIN images img ON img.user_id = users.user_id
    LEFT JOIN products prod ON prod.user_id = users.user_id
    WHERE user.user_id <= 5) AS users
    ORDER BY user.user_id ASC
```

The result should be the following output. Due to performance improvements, I use ORDER BY and an inner select. If I put a LIMIT 5 within the inner or outer select, things won't work. MySQL will hard LIMIT the results to 5. However I need the LIMIT of 5 (pagination) found unique user_id results which would lead to 9 in this case. 
Can I use maybe an if-statement to push an array with found user_id and break/finish up the select when the array consist of 5 UIDs? Or can I modify somehow the select?

```
user_id user_name img_type prod_id
1 andrew  0   5
1 andrew  1   5
1 andrew  0   55
1 andrew  1   55
2 lutz  0   5
2 lutz  0   55
3 sophie null null
4 michael null null
5 peter null null

results: 9
```

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: what exactly you want to `select`?

Comment: You can try to group your results by user_id. But then you will not get all images and products to your user_id. I think you want to do two different things in one query.

Comment: I can't group, I need every value of the child tables, including null values.

Comment: @Strawberry: What should this link be useful for? I don't see it.

Answer (score 0):

`LIMIT 5` and `user_id <= 5` do not necessarily give you the same results.  One reason: There are multiple rows (after the `JOINs`) for `user_id = 1`.  This is because there can be multiple images and/or multiple products for a given 'user'.

So, first decide which you want.

`LIMIT` without `ORDER BY` gives you an arbitrary set of rows.  (Yeah, it is somewhat predictable, but you should *not* depend on it.)

`ORDER BY + LIMIT` *usually* implies gathering all the potentially relevant rows, sorting them, *then* doing the "limit".  There are *sometimes* ways around this sluggishness.

`LEFT` leads to the `NULLs` you got; did you want that?

What do you want pagination to do if you are displaying 5 items per page, but user 1 has 6 images?  You need to think about this edge case before we can help you with a solution.  Maybe you want *all* of user 1 on a page, even if it exceeds 5?  Maybe you want to break in the middle of '1'; but then we need an unambiguous way to know where to continue from for the next page.

Probably any viable solution will not use nested `SELECTs`.  As you are finding out, it leads to "errors".  Think of it this way:  First find all the rows you need to display on all the pages, *then* carve out 5 for the current page.

Here are some more musings on pagination:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/pagination